# iterate across columns for mann whitney u test?

Tags: python

I'm looking to iterate across columns to conduct a mann-whitney u test,

```
for i in range(1000):
df2=df.sample(n=size_of_N, replace=False,random_state=i)
treatment_group=df2.iloc[:size_of_n]
control_group=df2.iloc[size_of_n:]
significance_list=[]
for column in list_of_columns:
    significance=mannwhitneyu(treatment_group[column],
                              control_group[column])
    significance_list.append(significance)
    min_p_value = min(significance_list)
    min_p_value_list.append(min_p_value)
```

but the code breaks in the line significance=mannwhitneyu(treatment_group[column],control_group[column]) with the following error message `"ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''"`

I've checked and all my data types are numeric and non-null, with no commas or percentage signs or anything.